# Flask + Heroku - Is AWS S3 the best way to store a static pickled database?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, flask

I am moving an application from desktop to heroku, and need to decide how to manage a moderately large static database (~500mb) of pickled timeseries that the app accesses often.

Being static resources, my first thought would be to follow the heroku guide and host them on S3 [as suggested in this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) and access them via [boto's s3 functions](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html) (as I don't need to serve the data to the web directly, but to use it in the background).

Is this the best approach to manage a static database, and are there reasons to maybe use heroku's [postgres db](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python) instead? Thanks

Comment: you said "static database", but what does that mean? How often does the data change? (once per minute, once per week, etc)

Comment: The database contains economic timeseries and is 95% static, and 5% changes weekly. By 95% / 5% I mean that the db is broken down in different files, each file containing a set number of rows. Only the file containing the most recent rows must be updated weekly, and its size is approx 10-30mb.

Comment: great. so "at worst" it is updated weekly. I'll compose an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard answer is that you need to use a real database. But in your case you simply have *internal static data*.

You can load picked data, or you can serialize to JSON and reload that (it's at least readable), you can use BTrees, or you can use SQLite saved from a file.

The disadvantages of the first two are that you need to load the dataset into memory. If your database is large (or your instances are small) you'll get into a memory crunch. The last two, btrees (a key-value store) and sqlite, give you alternatives. btrees is k-v and SQLite gives you a more traditional relational database interface.

Another thing to keep in mind is how you want to cache the s3 access. Presumably you aren't going to download and deserialize it every call. Do you do it on a release/startup? Do you check the sha hash or custom metadata? That's up to your specific use case.

I do something similar for an app that needs to keep state of a small number of items. I write it locally and to S3, and I only restore from S3 if the file is missing (since it only runs on one machine). That doesn't quite fit your use case but it's similar.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful and confirms my understanding. On the short term, I can stay with pickled data on S3, memory not being an issue (this was solved already for the laptop application). Later I can move to dumping data in postgres.

Comment: Worth noting that, months later, I ended up with a proper db service (in this case, MongoDB)